# How does animateWithDuration know what to animate?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am just learning some basic Objective-C and iOS development for the first time so please bear with me.  I am very familiar with the concept of lambdas from other languages, but this is my first time using Objective-C blocks.

So, following a UIKit animation tutorial, I thought I'd extend it by animating the background colour.  I wrote this:

```
- (void) setBG: (float)r g:(float)g b:(float)b duration:(float)secs
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:secs delay:0.0 options:0
                     animations:^{
                         [self setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:1.0]];
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}
```

So, I expected to need somehow to tell `animateWithDuration` what variables needed animating.  I started this from an example that animated a position (so, x and y), and thought I might need to make some changes to animate 3 variables.

However, to my surprised, this "just worked."  Somehow the language seems to have automatically determined that I wanted to animate `r`, `g`, and `b`.  Is the compiler actually introspecting the block?  What is happening here?  How does `animateWithDuration` know which variables I want it to modify over time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler doesn't interpret your code in that way. It's entirely done by the `UIView` class .

I don't know the exact internal implementation obviously, but one possible way would be to use a `shouldAnimate` flag in `UIView`. The `animateWithDuration:...` class method could turn this flag on before executing the animations block you pass. The setter methods of animatable properties of a `UIView` might then check for this flag to decide whether it needs to be animated:

```
- (void)setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)newColor {
    if (shouldAnimate) {
        // set up and start animation.
    } else {
        _backgroundColor = newColor;  // just set without animating.
    }
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

After executing the animations block, the `animateWithDuration:...` finally turns off the flag again, so when you set any `UIView` property outside an animation block, it's not animated.

Comment: Hm, I added an NSLog statement to the block and it only gets printed once.  This tells me that you're probably right in that setBackgroundColor is called once, but is probably specially written to animate the values?  animateWithDuration somehow transfers the "duration" value to the background colour animator.

Answer (score 2):

The `UIView` class has private variables that track whether you're inside an animation block, and what the parameters of the animation are.

The setters for various `UIView` properties check that state.  If the setter finds that it's being called inside an animation block, it creates an animation for the property.  (The animation is an instance of `CABasicAnimation` attached the view's layer.)

The animatable properties are listed in the [*UIView Class Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW131):

- `frame`
- `bounds`
- `center`
- `transform`
- `alpha`
- `backgroundColor`
- `contentStretch`

Answer (score 0):

`UIView animateWithDuration` uses linear interpolation between the starting state (the original value) and the ending state (the values you set in the animations block). Imagine a graph of the variable value over time. Using the desired duration and the two points, it creates a line between (0 seconds, start value) and (duration, end value). As the animation plays, the value updates based on a point moving along the line over time.

So, I believe that the colour is broken down into values (rgb would be a logical guess). We have a start value and end value for each element and it changes over the animation duration.